# Different results with invoke-command vs local command

Tags: windows, powershell

Why does `Invoke-Command` give different results when commands run remotely than it does when the exact same commands are run locally on the exact same system?

These remotely invoked commands display 4 empty lines:

```
PS > Invoke-Command cluster02 { cmd /c dir c:\ | select-string 'bytes free' }
```

While these local commands output as expected:

```
PS > Invoke-Command cluster02 { cmd /c dir c:\ | select-string 'bytes free' }

11 Dir(s) 828,179,570,688 bytes free
```

If I first start an `Enter-PSSession cluster02` and then run them, both commands return the expected output.

Is it a bug on this old PowerShell (windows 2012) or do I miss some PS peculiarity? If it's a bug or peculiarity when does it manifest? In other words is there something to learn from this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is you're trying to run remote `cmd /c` with a cmd `dir` command and then pipe that over to a PowerShell command remotely.

While you are expecting this to work exactly the way it does locally when you are running it remotely, this is known to have differences and cause confusion.

As stated in the [Commands that Need a User Profile May Fail When Run Remotely](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/the-big-book-of-powershell-gotchas/commands-that-need-a-user-profile-may-fail-when-run-remotely) post

> The problem is that, when you connect to a remote computer, you aren’t
> spinning up a complete user environment. You’re technically not
> “logging on” to the machine in the usual sense. You’re authenticating,
> yes, but in much the same way that you’d authenticate to a shared
> folder. Your remote connection doesn’t have a complete user profile,
> and so anything that’s expecting one can get errors and fail (even if
> they don’t show those errors).
>
> There’s no easy fix for this, unfortunately.

When I run `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {}` against a remote machine, I try to keep the commands as PowerShell as possible. You should test extensively if you're mixing cmd and PowerShell as it may not work the same way as it does when you run it while logged onto the system interactively.

### Remote PowerShell, get drive free space in bytes (no `cmd`)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Cluster02 -ScriptBlock {(Get-PSDrive C).Free}
```

#### Output

```
599257099776
```

---

## Workarounds

Setting the output of the `Invoke-Command` as a variable, and then selecting the string and the line property from it seems to do the trick for the desired output you prefer.

### PowerShell (Variation 1)

```
$var = Invoke-Command cluster02 -ScriptBlock { cmd /c "dir c:\" }; 
($var| select-string 'bytes free').Line.Trim();
```

### Output

```
11 Dir(s)  36,011,925,504 bytes free
```

**The issue is likely** due to invoking `cmd /c` and then PowerShell pipe selecting the matching string from it in the remote invoked session. I work around that problem by saving the full output from the `invoke-command` that returns correctly as a variable outside the `invoke-command`, and then parse that variable accordingly outside the `invoke-command` as well.

### PowerShell (Variation 2)

Here's the same deal as above but rather than throwing a variable into the mix, just pipe the `Invoke-Command` right over to the `Select-String` query.

```
Invoke-Command cluster02 -ScriptBlock { cmd /c "dir c:\"; } | select-string 'bytes free';
```

Or even something like this...

```
(Invoke-Command cluster02 -ScriptBlock { cmd /c "dir c:\"; } | select-string 'bytes free').Line.Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

*(please upvote the accepted answer also if you liked this TLDR version)*

**TLDR Guidelines**

When running script blocks remotely:

- If possible, avoid running anything that is not native PowerShell. E.g. replace  `cmd /c dir c:\|sls 'bytes free'` with `(Get-PSDrive C).Free`.
- If not, do the least amount of processing in the remote shell. E.g. move select-string outside the remote shell like so: `Invoke-Command cluster02 { cmd /c "dir c:\" } | sls 'bytes free'`.